# How to convert an image_tag to link_to on the fly using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, galleria

I have this code in my view:

```
  <div id='contentFlow' class='ContentFlow' useAddOns="DEFAULT white highslide" style="height:auto;">
  <div class="loadIndicator"><div class="indicator"></div></div>
  <div class="flow">

  <% @exhibit.image_pages.each do |t|%>
       <div class="item">
       <%= image_tag t.image.url,:class=>'content',:href=>"#{t.image.image.thumb('1280x800').url}" %>
         <div class="caption"><%= raw t.caption %></div>
       </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
  <div class="globalCaption"></div>
  <div class="scrollbar"><div class="slider"></div></div>
```

I want to use Galleria, which only accepts `<a>..</a>` links and I need to make the following modifications:

- remove `<div class="caption"><%= raw t.caption %></div>`.
- convert`<%= image_tag

  t.image.url,:class=>'content',:href=>"#{t.image.image.thumb('1280x800').url}"
  %>` to  `<%= link_to

  image_tag(t.image.thumbnail('200x200').url,:title=>"#{raw

  t.caption}"),t.image.image.thumb('1280x800').url %>`

on the fly using jQuery.

Comment: And what have you tried in order to achieve this? And please post the rendered HTML, not the server side code, as JavaScript works client-side.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague on how you actually want to use this, and why you need to do it on-the-fly. My first reaction is to create a view that renders what you want want and return it via Ajax.